# Adding authentication to a WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, authentication

I'm trying to create a simple, authenticated, NuGet Feed over http, so I followed the steps pointed out in http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds. It works well, but I want the feed to require authentication, which supposedly is supported by the client.

When I added the NuGet.Server package to my brand new Asp.net MVC project, it added this route:

```
var factory = new DataServiceHostFactory();
var serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute("nuget", factory, typeof(Packages));
serviceRoute.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
serviceRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
routes.Add("nuget", serviceRoute);
```

No configuration was changed.

This makes the URL http://{host}/nuget/Packages actually contain the feed with all the packages, but it is completely unauthenticated. I want to in some way, preferrably without adding 2 tons of XML, be able to hook into the pipeline for the Packages service (which I do not control) and perfomr some kind of authentication then. What is the (simplest) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack has a blog post on implementing an Authorization Attribute for WCF.  Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/19/implementing-an-authorization-attribute-for-wcf-web-api.aspx